# How do you return a memberVariable (Object) and the reset it without resetting the returned member variable of before?

Tags: java

How do you return a memberVariable (containing Object)

- without inefficient copying (duplicating in memory) the member variable's object

and then reset the member variable

- without overriding the returned member variable's object for the Observers getting the 'copy' of before?

Here's an example code:

```
public class SomeClass extends Observable {

  private Object someObject;

  private void whenSomethingHappens() {
    this.setChanged();        
    this.notifyObservers(someObject); // TODO: return the object without copying it in RAM
    this.someObject = new Object(); // TODO: create a new empty object somwhere else in RAM such as it doesn't override the returned object of before
  }

}
```

Comment: These seem like contrary requirements. Either the method uses the same object as is stored in the member field (first requirement) or it uses a different object (second requirement). In each case, the other requirement is violated.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want...though I suspect it's already doing what you want.  Java passes references by value; `notifyObservers(someObject)` does not make a copy of `someObject` (unless you actually explicitly make a copy in the `notifyObservers` implementation).

Comment: You don't. You can't make a copy without making a copy. Don't optimize prematurely. The copy is probably not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you have already does what you want.

```
this.notifyObservers(someObject)
```

This passes the reference to someObject to the method `notifyObservers`. No new object has been created, so no additional memory has been used up (other than creating an additional reference to the existing object).

```
this.someObject = new Object();
```

This creates a new object in memory and then overwrites the reference `someObject`. If `notifyObservers` stored a reference to the original object, it is not affected by this line of code.

Comment: You are so right! Sorry for the confusion! I was convinced that it will override the passed object, but in fact it doesn't.

Comment: I can't believe i never questioned or realised this before! That has just revolutionised my thinking when I'm programming in Java.:) Thank you!